# Scrolling to last appended item breaks after X appended items

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a scrollable div where i append dynamically some items, on each appended item i scroll to the last one to keep the last item ever visibly, but after i add X items the scroll just breaks by scrolling down and up.

```js
function addProdotto(prodotto) {
  $(".prodotti").append(
    $("<div>", { class: "prodotto" })
      .text(prodotto.desc)
      .append(
        $("<span>").text(prodotto.prezzo),
        prodotto.promo &&
          $("<div>", { class: "promo" })
            .text(prodotto.promo.desc)
            .append($("<span>").text(prodotto.promo.prezzo))
      )
  );
  $(".prodotti").animate({ scrollTop: $(".prodotto").last().offset().top });
}

$('.addProducts').on('click', function() {
addProdotto({ desc: "TEST", prezzo: "2.00€", promo: { desc: "PROMO 20%", prezzo: "0.20€" } });
})
```

```css
.header {
    background-color: red;
    height: 80px;
}

.prodotti {
    padding: 1rem;
  height: calc(100vh - 160px);
  overflow: auto;
}

.bottom {
    height: 80px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <button type="button" class="addProducts">
      ADD
    </button>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12 header">

          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-12 main">
            <div class="prodotti">

            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-12 bottom">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

As you could see after you add lot of items the scroll just breaks and stop scrolling to the last item and just goes up and down..

Comment: @Andreas just added the fiddle with the reproducible code

Comment: It works for me if you wait for the animation to end and only then add the next element. If you add one while the animation is still running its broken from that moment on.

Comment: @Andreas try to add couple of items, even if i wait like 5 seconds before adding a new item it's breaks..

Comment: For me it works as described in my comment. If I wait for the animation to finish, I can add as many items as I like (I stopped at 30)

Comment: @Andreas which browser are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the issue by doing the .animate directly on `$('.prodotti')` where i append the new item and by using `.prop('scrollHeight')` instead so my solution looks like this:

```
function addProdotto(prodotto) {
  $(".prodotti").append(
    $("<div>", { class: "prodotto" })
      .text(prodotto.desc)
      .append(
        $("<span>").text(prodotto.prezzo),
        prodotto.promo &&
          $("<div>", { class: "promo" })
            .text(prodotto.promo.desc)
            .append($("<span>").text(prodotto.promo.prezzo))
      )
  )  .animate({ scrollTop: $(".prodotti").prop("scrollHeight") }, "slow");
}
```